# Electron: Inject raw html into BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Is it possbile to inject raw html code into a `BrowserWindow`?

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 800});
mainWindow.loadURL("<p>Hello, World!</p>");
```

The above code will crash because `loadURL` only accepts a file path.

Comment: You might be able to do this with webContents: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md But may I ask why you want to do this? I feel there is likely a better way.

Comment: I'm using the swig template system (http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) which compiles the templates and returns the raw html.

Comment: I dont think webContent is any solution to my question. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use data urls to accomplish this:

```
mainWindow.loadURL("data:text/html,<p>Hello, World!</p>");
```

Comment: but page-navigation via #id is not possible this way. Chromium throws following exception: `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL`